# Opening a user's Apple Mail to make a new outgoing message with pre-populated HTML body

Tags: django, email, html-email, apple-mail

Is there a way to provide a link that opens a users Apple Mail and pre-populates the email with an HTML body?  I know this is not really possible with mailto as it's outside the spec of plain/text.  I'm working on a Django app, and I'd like the user to be able to click on a link to open their Apple Mail with a new message that has HTML.  I know there are security risks involved with mail clients allowing more than just plain text, but I wanted to see if anyone had any thoughts.